# How to display UIView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard

i like to display a uiview in the storyboard so i don't have to do the design programatically.
I saw some tutorials from older versions of XCode, but it do not seem to work in XCode 5.
Do i something wrong? I know basically how to implement it with code and show it.

I saw that you have to set the Size to FreeForm and then you can adjust it and add it to other views, just like in the code.

I want to develop an iOS 7 App by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you actually _try_ to make this work?

Comment: Because i want to create a "pattern" for an app. So i want to basically have a little window that i can show and hide whenever i want.
I have something like a test, in which it is necessary to show/hide 2 different windows and i don't want to use multiple Views in my Storyboard, because this process repeats like 10 times or so. 
I am new to iOS development, so maybe there are much more better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use storyboard and have autolayout set then it is really hard for you to set the sizes of your view. Since you only need a `UIView` to display in your storyboard try this approach.

- Add new file , select user Interface
- It doesnt matter what you select the type of UI
- Make sure the your classes are subclasses of UIView

Now it creates a new xib for you. Open that xib and delete what see in the interface builder. Now drag a UIView on to the interface builder. You can rezise it and modify it as you want . And when you need it you can do something like this

```
MyViewClass* myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewClassNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Update:

create your view like this .h file

```
@interface CardView : UIView
{    
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *rating_btn;

-(IBAction)rating:(id)sender;
+ (id)cardView;
```

your .m file

```
 +(id)cardView
{
    CardView *cardView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    if ([cardView isKindOfClass:[CardView class]])
    {
        return cardView;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}

-(IBAction)rating:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button pressed");
}
```

Use these in your main view controller like this

```
CardView *card = [CardView cardView];
[self addSubview:card];
```

Make sure you connect your UIView buttons.

Comment: It works that way. But i want it to have buttons and just data displaying. So how do i connect a ViewController to it? I tried it the normal way. Add files and connecting it by writing the class name to the identity inspector, but it hadn't been recognized by the view. Is there a way to do that in general?

Comment: i tried to use a UIWindow, but then it hides the main view when i show it.

Comment: You cannot use UIWindow for what you are trying to achieve . Se the updated answer

Comment: One more question: Why do i need the if-statement in the +(id)cardView?
Isn't it obvious for the compiler that it is a CardView?

Comment: when you make a call to loadyour nib there is change that you will get more than one nib back. So it basically returns you a array of nibs that it found. See that we are getting last object from out array. Some people get the `objectAtIndex:0` . By using that if condition we are making sure that if got the correct nib and we are returning it .

Comment: Oh I got your question now. I updated it. Sorry for missing it.